# Unable to pick latest files based on created date using Scala

Tags: scala

I am working on a Scala program that will list all the log files in a folder and its sub directories based on their creation date.
So far, this is the code I came up with:

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTimeZone}
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.io.File
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

def getFileTree(f: File): Stream[File] =
    f #:: (if (f.isDirectory) f.listFiles().toStream.flatMap(getFileTree) 
        else Stream.empty)
val files = getFileTree(new File("/props/audits/")).filter(_.getName.endsWith(".log"))
val t = (x:Long) => { new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(x)}
files.toList.map(y => t(y.lastModified))
val latestFiles = files.toList.map(y => (y,t(y.lastModified)))
```

The folder has the files from the dates as following:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 2 in2429OV in2429OV  4096 Dec  8 17:01 170150_logs
drwxrwxr-x. 2 in2429OV in2429OV  4096 Dec  8 17:06 170500_logs
drwxrwxr-x. 2 in2429OV in2429OV  4096 Dec  8 19:38 171200_logs
drwxrwxr-x. 2 in2429OV in2429OV  4096 Dec 11 12:31 176800_logs
drwxrwxr-x. 2 in2429OV in2429OV  4096 Dec 11 12:34 177150_logs
drwxrwxr-x. 2 in2429OV in2429OV 12288 Dec 11 12:38 177500_logs
drwxrwxr-x. 2 in2429OV in2429OV  4096 Dec 11 16:05 177850_logs
drwxrwxr-x. 2 in2429OV in2429OV  4096 Dec 11 16:10 178200_logs
drwxrwxr-x. 2 in2429OV in2429OV 12288 Dec 12 07:19 200950_logs
drwxrwxr-x. 2 in2429OV in2429OV 12288 Dec 12 07:20 201300_logs
```

The problem I am facing here is that, in the output, I could see the files with the dates only from: 2017-12-08
The files present inside the folders created on the days: 11th and 12th December are not listing.

Output:

```
(/props/audits/171200_logs/171200_xx_po_control_rules_diagnostic.log,2017-12-08), 
(/props/audits/171200_logs/171200_xx_fnd_document_categories_diagnostic.log,2017-12-08), 
(/props/audits/171200_logs/171200_xx_internal_bank_account_documents_diagnostic.log,2017-12-08), 

(/props/audits/171200_logs/171200_xx_ar_invoices_diagnostic.log,2017-12-08),

 (/props/audits/171200_logs/171200_xx_fnd_lookup_types_diagnostic.log,2017-12-08),
```

Since there are sub folders inside the main folder, I filtered the output that only has the ".log" extension.
If I take out the filter option in this statement:    `val files = getFileTree(new File("/props/audits/")).filter(_.getName.endsWith(".log"))`

then I can see the latest modified date of the main folder, but only the main folder's date is listed as below:

```
val latestFiles = files.toList.map(y => (y,t(y.lastModified)))
latestFiles: List[(java.io.File, String)] = List((/props/audits/,2017-12-12), (/props/audits/171200_logs),(/props/audits/171200_logs/171200_xx_po_control_rules_diagnostic.log,2017-12-08),..
```

The output contains files more than 15000 files. After some research, I've found out that the list: latestFiles is not ordered

Could anyone tell me how can I check the date of the dir with current date and only then load the files in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to hold all the values"? Do you run out of memory? Why do you convert it to a `List` to begin with? Also, though not directly related to your question, if you are only looking for latest (your code isn't actually doing that), perhaps, it would make sense to start with folder timestamps and only looks the newer ones to make it more efficient?

Comment: @Dima, Thats exactly what I want to do.But I couldn't come up with a solution of checking the folder's timestamp with current time stamp and only then get into files inside it.

I had edited the question. The list: latestFiles is not ordered and I have corrected it.

Comment: The code itself doesn't look wrong. I suggest for you to try the following: 1. show some contents of both new/old folders (with sizes and permissions like for root /audits folder) 2. what happens if you manually change dates of new folders to become older ones, e.g. using command "touch -t 201712072000 <folder>"? will their contents appear on application rerun?